# iSight webcam doesn’t work on MacBook Core 2 Duo

Tags: drivers, webcam

I don't know if this is the right place to open this discussion, but I have a problem that I can't solve.

I installed elementary OS on a MacBook Core 2 Duo (A1181), in dual boot with OS X Lion. I had no problems except the failure of the integrated webcam. I searched the net for guides to solve the problem. Almost all of them lead me to extract the driver from OS X:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight
- https://turanct.wordpress.com/tag/appleusbvideosupport/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m97YJ-Qfdi8

I was able to find and save the `AppleUSBVideoSupport` file of the webcam, but the conversion operation to get the `Isight.fw` file for linux is not successful.

Does someone have the `Isight.fw` file already extracted and/or do you know where it can be found?

Thanks